# Is it possible to not hardcode express based server ip in a react based frontend app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a backed app written in typescript which has an express server running on port 5001. I have a front end app written using react. Both these apps are hosted on same machine.

The react app needs to fetch data from the backed app using the port 5001 being served by express server.

The machine has an IP of 10.250.1.4 for example. So from the host machine, I could use localhost:5001 or 10.250.1.4:5001 in the axios requests and both will work.

The react development server in this case is running at Port 3000 for the front end app.

When another client machine, running on 10.250.1.6 for example, tries to access 10.250.1.4:3000 from its browser, the react app is sent to the client. In this case the axios requests from the client to backed server will only run if the axios is looking at the 10.250.1.4 rather than localhost.

I wish to write the axios in front end app in a way that I don't have to specify the ip of the express server. Both the front end and backed app will always be hosted at same machine.

Is there a way?

Thanks.

Comment: From within the client, you can always extract the hostname from the current web page URL and use that.  Since you said the two servers are always on the same host, that should always work.  You will, of course, have to insert the proper port since that is different.